# Sort a whole row based on a checkbox on appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

hope you are doing well.

I'm trying to sort a row that contains 18 cells based on checkboxes. Each checkbox assigns a task to each person and I basically would like to group people who are working on each task.

[People with tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CsIN.png)

As you can see in the screenshot it's difficult to identify each task. I would like that all the people who are working on the "new" task to be together and not separated and People who are working on the "Open" task to be in a group below the "New" task

Another problem I have is that I'm getting these names (column A) from a formula based on another list.

Do you think is there a way to this action works? or it's not possible? I found this code based on other values but I'm not sure if I could modify it to achieve the action I want. This is the code:

```
function autoSort(e) {
  
  const row = e.range.getRow()
  const column = e.range.getColumn()
  const ss = e.source
  const currentSheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  const currentSheetName = currentSheet.getSheetName()

  if(!(currentSheetName === "Assignation" && column === 2 && row >= 2)) return

  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Assignation")

  const range = ws.getRange (2,2, ws.getLastRow()-1,7)

  range.sort({column: 1, ascending: false})
  
}

function onEdit(e){

  const row = e.range.getRow()
  const column = e.getRange.getColumn()

  if(!(column === 1 && row >= 2)) return

  autoSort()
}
```

Also, this is the sheet I'm using, it's a copy so you can modify it as you want.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f5Mu2SKPAYKC9UcpDOkGdtS6JeFDHcsqPMmuZyz-zWA/edit?usp=sharing

I hope anyone can help me with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I weighted them by their column index

```
function groupsort() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 18).getValues();
  const idxs = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  vs.sort((a, b) => {
    let va = idxs.reduce((acc, idx, i) => {
      acc += a[idx] ? idx : 5;
      return acc;
    }, 0)
    let vb = idxs.reduce((acc, idx, i) => {
      acc += b[idx] ? idx : 5;
      return acc;
    }, 0)
    return va - vb;
  });
  sh.getRange(2, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Sheet0 Before:

[image]

Sheet0 After:

[image]

Comment: Hey Cooper! thank you for your response, I can see it works but unfortunately it changes the data I have in columns 20 and 21 as well. Is there a way to get this same sort function with a limit in the rows it is changing? I mean to change just rows of columns 1 to 18

Also, I can see all the names go to the end of the column once I run the code, is there a way to get the names on the top?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: The five columns I just put in there to make sure that the entire row was being sorted.

Comment: Now it's setup for just the first 18 columns

Comment: I reversed the sort order

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again Cooper, actually it's amazing, it works perfectly, I just would like that the task "New" appears on the top before the task "Open" and the task Open before the "P-A" task and so on.

Basically, it would be great if the sorting is the other way around. Do you think it's possible? or what should I change to achieve this?

Comment: Sure @Cooper Thank you so much! In the second screenshot, you shared I can see the name 1, 4, 7, and 10 that belongs to column 2 are on the top rows, and the group of column 3 are below column 1 rows but when I run the code I get the column 2 group at the bottom and the column 3 group above of column 2 rows. I tried to change it in the code but I keep getting the same result.

Comment: I just updated the code and the image.  I think the current has what you want.

Comment: Awesome! it's perfect, thank you so much!
Hey @Cooper, I was wondering if you accept any donations.